# Trying to run a simple Yammer Api

Tags: yammer

I'm trying to get a simple Yammer REST api running, specifically this one:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/topics/:Topic_ID.json

or

https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/topics/:Topic_ID.json

(From https://developer.yammer.com/docs/topicsidjson)

For me, even when using the "try out" tool on the page, it returns a 404 error. 
I know my token works because it works with some YammerAPIs, it's just a handful that doesn't work, which I need.

Currently I'm calling the REST endpoints using ajax/js, and I'm getting a "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/:769359386.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Any ideas?

- I have already added my domain to the "Javascript Origins" in my app settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/:769359386.json

remove the `:` before the topic ID. It should be:

> https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/769359386.json